# Node js get js of socket.io

Tags: node.js, socket.io

How do i load the js of socket.io.js into a variable inside my node server app.

I want to create a route '/jsfile' with express where i send the socket.io.js file + some js functions all in one js.

I can't get the socket.io.js from my server with fs readFile / readFileSync

Answer (score 2):

You need to `require` dependencies  after installing them via `npm`. [The readFile API](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfile_filename_options_callback) should be used to.. wel read files.

First install socket-io

```
npm install --save socket-io
```

Then in your node application, do

```
var io = require('io');
```

Comment: Well i'm not sure you understand what i want.. I have installed them. I have the server up and running. But i want to send in one file the socket.io.js contents + other content one the '/jsfile' route

Comment: I don't understand, why do you want to send the node variant of socket.io to your client?

Comment: I want to let other sites connect to my socket.io server. I want to add something to the socket.io.js file before sending it to the User Site. Something like var user_id = 111; plus some functions.
So when the user put in his website that "<script src='myserver.com/jsfile'" they will get the socket.io.js content + my own content

Comment: Don't do it like that, make a script that does an async call to your socket endpoint. Include the needed variables and functions in that script.